# Making a default value in a first row

Tags: java, constants

[image]

I have this code that add row depends on the user input, but now I want the first row of the second column to have a default value of 0 and the rest of it is null.

Code of the table

```
DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();

 table.setModel(dm);


            dm.addColumn("PROCESS");
            dm.addColumn("CPU Time");
            dm.addColumn("Arrival Time");


 try{
        int ps = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());



        for(int x=0; x<ps; x++){
            dm.addRow(new Object[]{x});
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain your question?

Comment: uhm i want to have a default value of 0 on the first row second column and the rest should be null. if i use dm.addRow(new Object[]{x,0}); all the rows in the second column have 0 because of the loop what i want is only the first row would have a value

Comment: first of all I do not understand what is "all the rows in second coulmn" it doesnt look like 2-d array to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `addRow` twice with different arguments: first adding the row with `0`, and then (in a loop) adding the remaining rows:

```
dm.addRow(new Object[]{x, 0});
for (int x=1; x<ps; x++) {
    dm.addRow(new Object[]{x});
}
```

Notice that the loop is now one iteration shorter than in your code (because the first row gets added outside the loop).